# New Gas Double Oven:The GFI suddenly started tripping during preheat

Tags: gas, oven

I installed new gas double oven using the same line from prior electric oven. Installed new 20 amp breaker and new 20 GFI outlet.
The GFI  outlet is tripping every time i preheat oven.
Is there something wrong with the wire?

Comment: Is the receptacle concealed behind the oven(difficult to access)?  Do the oven's labeling and instructions take any position on putting it on a GFCI?

Comment: What make and model is the oven?